# Is Rejas' deal with Calderon implemented?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dancer-upstairs

After Yolanda is sentenced in Malkovich's 2002 movie *THe Dancer Upstairs*, Rejas negotiates laxer terms on her behalf.

Although she returns the blanket with a dismissive note, should it imply she refused the whole deal? It's part of a president's move and Yolanda being jailed, most terms can be forced on her.

And what about the inconsistent calligraphies she uses in her note: harsh detached capital characters for the message but smooth ones to write Rejas'name on the envelope? Is she even willing to refuse the whole deal? This calligraphies game is consistent with her ambivalent attitude toward Rejas throughout the movie.

Is the whole deal supposed to have collapsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is preposterous.

I missed the fact that Rejas sent the blanket before seeking a deal on her behalf. Actually I understood there were two garden scenes instead of one: deal negotiation and deal feedback. Thus Rejas sealed the deal after knowing Yolanda dismissed him.